# recognizing "4 days back" using @sys.date

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have an intent which takes date as input. I have used `@sys.date` to recognize date which is able to recognize many date formats including **today, 2 nov, 2 days ago**.
However, surprisingly it is not able to map phrase like **2 days back** to a specific date.
Is there any way to make it work?

[image: days ago]

[image: days back]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add to system entities (entities that start with `@sys`) but you can create your own composite date entity using a custom date unit entity (that includes "days back") and the system number entity:

1. Create a new `date-unit` entity with the value `days` and the synonym `days back`:
   [image]
   and save the entity
2. Create another entity called `Date`, uncheck the box for `Define synonyms` and enter `@sys.number @date-unit` for the value of the entity:
   [image]
   and save the entity
3. Next add the `X days back` training example to an intent, which should be auto-annotated (if not highlight the training phrase and annotate it manually):
   [image]
   and save the intent. Try it out by querying your agent with a `X days back` query.

The JSON you receive from this payload will vary based on if the `@sys.date` entity was recognized or if the `@Date` entity you just created was recognized.  The JSON payload for the `17 days back query` that your webhook will receive looks like this:

```
{
  "responseId": "1f67167c-8840-42ed-b3ed-420e2c2b1c43",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "17 days back",
    "parameters": {
      "Date": "17 days"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/anotheragent-c5ea8/agent/intents/6743e47a-8cb5-458d-b573-626d1a392a46",
      "displayName": "Date"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

so you'll need to add some logic in your webhook to parse this date type in addition to the `@sys.date` type.